# I have some questions about the Quran?

Tags: halal-haram, quran

Here are some question I want to ask about Islam :

1. I read it somewhere that muslims must learn Arabic (The language of Islam) I know how to read the quran in arabic but I don't know how to speak Arabic and I also don't understand a single word that I read in the Quran in arabic without seeing the translation . So tell me do I have to learn the Arabic inspite of the reading
2. Some of my school friends were saying that Prophet Muhammad founded the religion Islam but I abjured that and said that no there was Islam before Muhammad was born because once my mother told me about Prophet Adam alhai salaam that he was the first man on earth . After that much said my friends laughed at me and said that Prophet Muhammad was born in a non muslim family once again I rejected that . So please tell me Am I right or wrong ?
3. Now it seems a little complicated but still I want to ask this as you know I don't speak arabic but we have to offer salah in arabic by reciting the different Surah's . A question arises that why can't i offer salah in my own mother language why can't I translate surah fatiha and recite in my own language ?
4. It might going to offend some of you but It's nothing about disrespecting my religion . The question is why is it haraam to masturbate for a muslim teenager sorry If you got offensive but it's important to know that if allah said that a man can marry at the age of 12 but nowadays we can't marry at the age of 20 so tell me why can't teenagers masturbate ?
5. The last thing is  that shall I read the Q'ran in my own language to understand because many people says that its the book where you will get all your answers .

Regards !

Please answer the questions and clear my Doubts !

Comment: Salam and welcome on Islam Stack Exchange the Q&A site about Islam. Please consider splitting your questions as these are different and distinct questions and question topics. Also my impression is that most if not all of them have been asked on the site before, so you should find answers here. To learn more about our site and model I recommend you to check our [help] after taking our tour. (see also https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2965/why-we-should-avoid-asking-multi-question-questions)

Comment: Can you please answer my question ?

Comment: Some relevant posts: https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/44088/reciting-surats-without-knowing-the-true-meaning-of-it?, (see [tag:mastrubation]), https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/406/what-does-islam-say-about-reading-the-quran-in-a-language-other-than-arabic, https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/28030/language-for-prayers, https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/38/why-do-muslims-offer-prayers-in-arabic-what-is-the-significance-of-the-language and https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/30502/jesus-was-a-muslim